# Solutions of a partial differential equations

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

I'm looking for solutions of a PDE of the form :
$ P(t,x):[0,\infty]*[0,b]\rightarrow[0,1]$
$$ \partial_t P(t,x)= \partial_x [(1+2x) P(t,x)]$$
$$ P(0,x)=\delta_x (0)$$ 
$$P(t,b)=g(t)$$

Where $b$ is a boundary for $x$ and $g(t)$ is a known function. Is there anyone who knows how to solve this?

Comment: Change of variable $y=\log (2x+1)$?